# Laravel 8 - How to open mail client with attachment on link click?

Tags: php, email, laravel-8

Most resources explain the use of laravel mail as "automatic" or "on button click".

What I need is to have a button named "send email" so when clicked, it open email client with subject, body and attachments (PDF & ZIP) instead of using `<a href="mailto:email?subject=example?body=example">Send Email</a>`

Note that I am using

1. TCPDF for generating PDFs within the browser (Not saving it to PC
   nor server)
2. ZipArchive for downloading images as ZIP file

I want to attach these 2 in the mail when `<a>` is clicked.

Is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: You won't be able to attach a file that's not saved on the user's computer. And attaching a file from a browser click seems like a huge security issue.

Comment: No issues, I can save the file on the server to attach it to the email if possible

Comment: Files stored on the server cannot be sent to the user's email client. The best way to go about it would be to create an email form on your site to send the email, instead of relying on the user.

Comment: @KJ I meant to view the pdf in the browser instead of downloading it. Thanks everyone for your comments